# encoded text what is this and how to decode it?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web-applications, request, fetch-api

So I'm trying to find out how a web app works and I was looking at its requests the raw data was encoded like this what is this and how to reproduce it to use their api?

```
é£Ü-JM[#ÀóÚÀ5"Ò 
        ¿ eyJ4NXQiOiJOVEF4Wm1NeE5ETXlaRGczTVRVMVpHTTBNekV6T0RKaFpXSTRORE5sWkRVMU9HRmtOakZpTVEiLCJraWQiOiJOVEF4Wm1NeE5ETXlaRGczTVRVMVpHTTBNekV6T0RKaFpXSTRORE5sWkRVMU9HRmtOakZpTVEiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiJ9.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.fPGGaVObDPuhYOVhAPAk9mw_Vtiyzq-v43iCGuULLioPpuR73eb8f1ufB6Y5ZnX3zsPp7Mq-XkLC0wwiY_6_-ykDg3huNwmI-bpKxB0szQkolpShE0QyqQ93dS8sB5yaB_qoHvzhsWM1_sRfJB3F246MiYietw9UAqJsmFrXAEq2diX2idjNeAc_SuPqNBtd39qw6cUcchW1n8m5VyLXogO9gN5TzVntvmUIh9r047E87Fdm1mXZEiuLEub2ljrrIrK9-zuPmfQx4FuEr8CQOlwvunmALLVjSRK1WsVEFwSW8pmrXvsu0LZOMgEWoSb7zfYYa4m-gbmvMrsuWYQ7CQB P²> Ü¡©DÓW×}ÿº>        J 
 fa_IR
```

I'm just trying to understand the requests to the server so that I can reproduce them again to use their api.

Comment: It's a chunk of binary (which could be anything) with some embedded Base64. Welcome to the world of reverse engineering.

Comment: @DaveNewton Thanks I'm just trying my best out here :)

Answer (score 1):

That is base-64 encoded text. When decoded, this is what I got back:

{"x5t":"NTAxZmMxNDMyZDg3MTU1ZGM0MzEzODJhZWI4NDNlZDU1OGFkNjFiMQ","kid":"NTAxZmMxNDMyZDg3MTU1ZGM0MzEzODJhZWI4NDNlZDU1OGFkNjFiMQ","alg":"RS256"}

{"mibPrivileges":"FORCED_OTP","sub":"lilapn@carbon.super","kycStatus":"{"WyigPCWR2gD1oxeJy2o5sY":"c"}","iss":"https://localhost:14257/oauth2/token" ,"mobile":"09127790529","aud":"rjrJJ9WdfQ37_ue0C_KrAVJz1Cwa","UserOTPStatus":"FINAL","PartyId":"53576671","azp":"rjrJJ9WdfQ37_ue0C_KrAVJz1Cwa","scope":"openid","ForceChange":"False","exp":1675709204,"iat":1675708304,"jti":"711f3312-2c25-46b8-af7f-f46fa0fdef15"}

Comment: I got some useless characters between these json objects too what are those?

Comment: @Weston With zero context there's no way to know.

Comment: I'm just trying to the reverse engineering